# Logging php actions that are sended to mysql in file

Tags: php, mysql, logging, xampp

I´m currently working on a big project with is based on php and its connected to a mysql database. I wanna track the actions the clients are doing in a file. If they login I wanna log who is logging in. I wanna log when someone is adding data with a submit button to the db and who is adding the data.

Does someone of you have a example how he did it, or have an idea how to do that?

I hope you understand what I mean :)

Best regards

Comment: First problem: There is no such thing as a `phpMyAdmin Database` There is a `MySQL` or `mariaDB` database which you might be using `phpMyAdmin` to make maintaining the db easier. XAMPP now uses a `mariadb` database

Comment: It's simple, everytime query (for example update) is finish, you will do another query for log the action.

Comment: There is no magic involved. If you want to log an action, you have to write a query to insert some info into your logging table as part of each of those actions

Comment: If you want do do it in a file [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) is what you need. Just write down who's the user and what action he is taking.

Answer (score 0):

There are already libraries that can do it for you. One of them is [Monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog). Follow doc in README in order to set it up in your project.